# In Think Bayes book about Posterior mean

Tags: arithmetic

Page 24, Think Bayes by  Allen B. Downey.

Can you explain me how he compute mean by this code :

```
def Mean(suite): 
    total = 0 
    for hypo, prob in suite.Items(): 
        total += hypo * prob 
    return total
```

I'm actually no idea about this. The prob is computed by sum and normalized. So result of Normalize is the part of mean? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The code seems to be a direct translation of the definition $\text{mean}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i p_i$. With equal probabilities this becomes $p_i=1/n$.

Comment: Is it a pmf? Because the class suite inherits from Pmf() class so the way that I can compute mean is using this equation : $mean = ∑_{i=1}^n p_ix_i$

Comment: Yes, and your code seems to be a direct translation of that formula!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found more information that has an explanation and can answer my question on this website. It's very useful. Thank you very much @kjetil b halvorsen.

Visit : https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-use-a-probability-mass-function-to-calculate-the-mean-and-variance-of